# NoSuchMethoException on calling DefaultValidator.getValidFileName()

Tags: java, xss, esapi

I am trying to use getValidFileName (String, String, list, boolean) method of DefaultValidator class from ESAPI provided jar (esapi-2.0_rc11) to validate file name. But on run time getting No such method exception.

This is my code:

```
public static String getValidFileName(String input,String[] strFileExtns, Boolean isNullable) throws Exception
{   
    List <String> fileExtnsList = new ArrayList <String>();

if (strFileExtns != null && strFileExtns.length > 0)
    for(int i=0; i<strFileExtns.length; i++)
    fileExtnsList.add(strFileExtns[i]);

    return new DefaultValidator().getValidFileName("FileNameValidation", input, fileExtnsList, isNullable);
}
```

I am getting 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.getValidFileName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Z)Ljava/lang/String;`

Code present in the jar:

```
public String getValidFileName(String context, String input, List<String> allowedExtensions, boolean allowNull)
    throws ValidationException, IntrusionException
  {
    if ((allowedExtensions == null) || (allowedExtensions.isEmpty())) {
      throw new ValidationException("Internal Error", "getValidFileName called with an empty or null list of allowed Extensions, therefore no files can be uploaded");
    }

    String canonical = "";
    try
    {
      if (isEmpty(input)) {
        if (allowNull) return null;
        throw new ValidationException(context + ": Input file name required", "Input required: context=" + context + ", input=" + input, context);
      }

      canonical = new File(input).getCanonicalFile().getName();
      getValidInput(context, input, "FileName", 255, true);

      File f = new File(canonical);
      String c = f.getCanonicalPath();
      String cpath = c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);

      if (!(input.equals(cpath)))
        throw new ValidationException(context + ": Invalid file name", "Invalid directory name does not match the canonical path: context=" + context + ", input=" + input + ", canonical=" + canonical, context);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      throw new ValidationException(context + ": Invalid file name", "Invalid file name does not exist: context=" + context + ", canonical=" + canonical, e, context);
    }

    Iterator i = allowedExtensions.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
      String ext = (String)i.next();
      if (input.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext.toLowerCase()))
        return canonical;
    }

    throw new ValidationException(context + ": Invalid file name does not have valid extension ( " + allowedExtensions + ")", "Invalid file name does not have valid extension ( " + allowedExtensions + "): context=" + context + ", input=" + input, context);
  }
```

Someone please help me on this.

Comment: Did you finally get this working?  If so, could you tell us the solution as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError errors are often caused by a dependency issue.  If you are using maven (I assume you may be, as this error often occurs with it), troubleshoot the error as follows:

Try issuing "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose" on the command line and check that the library containing org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator is the version you intended.  If not, you can use the exclusions tag to exclude the incorrect version from the dependency that is including the incorrect version.

Also check that your resulting classpath lists the dependencies in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to push the JAR in my WEB project. But now i am getting follwing exception: